# How to configure django to generate signed urls for media files with Google Cloud CDN?

Tags: django, google-cloud-cdn

I am working on a project that requires load media files from Google Cloud CDN. Currently, I am loading the files in the form of urls - cdn.mydomain.com/image.jpg . But this requires to provide public access to the object. I need to generate signed url for secure access of these resources. I have checked django-storages. It provides signed url straight from the storage bucket but does not say anything about signed urls for CDN. How do I generate signed urls for Google Cloud CDN inside django and keep using the django-storages library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up writing a storage backend. The `settings.CUSTOM_DOMAIN` is the address of the CDN. My backend code is as follows -

```
class CustomGoogleCloudStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):
    custom_domain = settings.CUSTOM_DOMAIN

    def make_url(self, name):
        host = "https://" + self.custom_domain
        return urllib.parse.urljoin(host, name)

    def url(self, name):
        name = self._normalize_name(name)
        url = self.make_url(name)
        key_name, base64_key = get_storage_key()
        expiration_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1) #put your desired time here
        return sign_url(url, key_name, base64_key, expiration_time)
```

The `sign_url` function is taken from [GCP's github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/cdn/snippets.py).

Answer (score 2):

Django is a high-level Python Web framework. You might use the [Cryptographic signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signing/) feature used by Django with the signed URLs Python ([Programmatically creating signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#programmatically_creating_signed_urls)) described in Cloud CDN documentation. Take a look on both links and let us know if that helps to answer your inquiry.